# Can I use a post-conditional statement with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, sum, conditional-statements

This is how I get my sum

```
double? myVar = myList.Sum(x => x.MyItem);
```

Is-it possible to replace myVar with null if .Sum() return 0 in the same line ?

I don't want to use

```
if(myVar == 0) myVar = null;
```

Does LINQ have a post-conditional statement ?

Comment: What is the type of `MyItem`? Note that your "I don't want to use" seems to go the other way round - from null to 0, not 0 to null.

Comment: @JonSkeet It's a `double?` I edited the question !

Comment: What's wrong with the `if` statement then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want the reverse of the null-coalescing operator, and there's nothing in either LINQ or the C# language to do that for you. You could create your own extension method to do that if you wanted though:

```
public T? NullIfDefault<T>(this T? value) where T : struct
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return value;
    }
    return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(default(T), value.Value)
        ? null : value;
}
```

Then:

```
double? myVar = myList.Sum(x => x.MyItem).NullIfDefault();
```

(There are various other options for how you code `NullIfDefault`, e.g. using `Nullable<T>.GetValueOrDefault()` - you might want to play around to find the form you like most.)